# UIImage not showing on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have an `UINavigationController` extension that adds a `rightBarButton` to the `navigationBar`. I have to add it to 4 `navigationControllers` and the problem is that in 2  is showing correctly but the other 2 have the button without image. The button works in all 4 of them (even the ones that doesn't have the image)

```
func addReportButton() {

    let reportImage = UIImage(named: "report_btn")
    let reportButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: reportImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "reportButtonPressed")
    navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = reportButton
}
```

The following are screenshots from the debugger

[image: Screenshot only button]
[image: Screenshot button and image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the thing was that I had some code to remove the black line that is below the `navigationBar` and that was causing the problem